# Error: Unable to resolve action `mygh/my-action@main`, repository not found

Tags: github-actions

I have two private repositories on GitHub.

```
mygh/my-action
mygh/my-code
```

I'm trying to run a workflow from `mygh/my-code` that uses the custom action `mygh/my-action` but GitHub Actions fails with this error:

```
Failed to resolve action download info. Error: Unable to resolve action `mygh/my-action@main`, repository not found
Retrying in 12.717 seconds
Failed to resolve action download info. Error: Unable to resolve action `mygh/my-action@main`, repository not found
Retrying in 11.214 seconds
Error: Unable to resolve action `mygh/my-action@main`, repository not found
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Please let us know when you find the solution.

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: [This thread](https://github.community/t/github-action-action-in-private-repository/16063/6) is worth reading. It has work-around for using actions in private repo and when GitHub is going to add this feature (hint not any time soon for non-Enterprise users)

Answer (score 13):

Action repository needs to be set as **public**, at least that's a requirement for now.

However, `uses` doesn't need to point to repo necessarily. It can also point to a path [see docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-action-in-the-same-repository-as-the-workflow). This way you can either, checkout private repo containing action or have it in same repo where your workflow is.

Answer (score 9):

If you are on a GitHub Enterprise plan, [you can use actions from a private repo](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#allowing-access-to-components-in-a-private-repository).

In the repo with the action, go to Settings > Actions > General and change the **Access setting** to either **Accessible from repositories in the '{org}' organization** or **Accessible from repositories in the '{enterprise}' enterprise**.

In the repo where you are calling that action, you will need to make sure that the repo can call actions. Settings > Actions > General and pick an option for **Actions permissions** that covers all the actions you want to allow.

If you do not have an enterprise plan, then cloning the repo and calling the action locally [as described here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-action-inside-a-different-private-repository-than-the-workflow) is currently your only option.